# nvidia dali video decode from external_source buffer (instead of file)

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-deepstream, dali, tritonserver

[This](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-inference-with-triton-inference-server-and-dali/) article explains how to do image decoding and preprocessing on server side with Dali while using triton-inference-server.

I am trying to find something similar for doing video decoding from h.264 encoded bytes array on server side, before the input `"NTHWC"` array is passed to any of the video recognition models like in [mmaction2](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmaction2) or [swin-transformer](https://github.com/SwinTransformer/Video-Swin-Transformer), using ensemble model.

All I can find is how to load video from files, but nothing on loading videos from `external_source`.

Also, as a workaround, I guess I can do the desired thing using [python-backend](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/python_backend/tree/main/examples/preprocessing) by writing the encoded video bytes to a file, and preprocess the video, but that will not inherently support batch processing, and I will either have to handle the batch sequentially or by starting multiprocess pools for processing each batch. highly un-optimal I guess.

Any help is highly appreciated.